# Logic Unit Test with Xcode - DerivedData empty

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, cocoapods, xctest

I'm writing some logic unit tests for our existing app. When I run a test case I'm getting,

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/chinthaka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXX-cuqxyxigigmngzcvxbguttpluqva/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking'
>   ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Then I checked the DerivedData directory and it's contain XXXXXUnitTests.xctest file only.

[image]

Other Linker Flags contains -ObjC and -l(AFNetworking).

Framework Search Paths are as the attached image and it contains some pods too. (But AFNetworking is  not among them.)

[image]

Library Search Paths are look like this,

[image]

Is there anything else I have missed to check or configure. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue after I set "Build Active Architecture Only" setting of the test target to No.

Additionally, the iOS Development Target was iOS 9.3 and it had to be iOS 8.0.